# How do I enable Android Studio/IDEA closure folding for anomynous class in Java 8?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, java-8, code-folding

I really like Android Studio's code folding for anonymous class:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doSomething();
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

into

```
(AsyncTask) (params) -> {
    doSomething()
}.execute();
```

This folding option is under "closures" in the settings. I switched to Java 8 (using retrolambda) since I wanted to use lambda expressions, however now Android Studio doesn't fold anonymous class. Is there a way to re-enable it?

P.S. 
I know I can stay at Java 7 and Android Studio would fold single-method anonymous class into lambda expression, but I want to be able to type lambda expressions directly, while still have multi-method anonymous class folded.

Comment: When you move your cursor on the anonymous class and press `Ctrl + .`, it should fold it.

Comment: That folds it into new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {...}.execute();
Which doesn't show what is being overridden.

Comment: The code folding should only work for functional interfaces (interfaces with one method), I think that's why it doesn't work with `AsyncTask`, which is an abstract class. I might be wrong though.

Comment: It does work with folding anonymous class extending an abstract class as I showed above. However it seems to be disabled with folding functional interface when Java 8 is used.
P.S. Hell I would actually want it to fold into (AsyncTask) doInBackground(params) -> ...., but it is good enough I can see what is in the method

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set JDK location to java 8 in under project structure -> SDK Location

Right now Android Studio 2.1 does not support lambda notation for java 8 but there is workaround for that.

1. You need to enable Jack compiler to support this feature
2. Add 
       android {
         jackOptions {
           enabled true
         }
      }
   in build.gradle file
3. Also it would require Android Sdk Build-tools 24 or later. To download that open standalone SDK manager under sdk manager and download